# how can I make a node always have its rotation facing down? Godot 4

Tags: godot

in Godot 4, I'm using a path node, and I would like to have the follower not spin, how would i do that?
sorry if this is a stupid question. its a 2d environment.

I've tried setting the rotation, but that always ended horribly.

Answer (score 1):

I was being stupid, for people ahead of me, there's a box on the path follow node. its titled "rotates" and if its off, it doesn't spin.